# Why elements in an array elements shift?

Tags: c, embedded

I am using stm32f4. In my project, i have one transmitter and one receiver.

i transmit an 2 byte integer value using

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,&temp_byte1,sizeof(temp_byte1), 500);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,&temp_byte2,sizeof(temp_byte2), 500);
```

and on the receiver part. i read these values using

```
uint8_t temp_data[2];
uint8_t rx_data;
uint8_t rx_index=0;
uint16_t temp;
void USART6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart6,&rx_data,1);
    temp_data[rx_index]=rx_data;
    rx_index++;
    if(rx_index==2)
    {
        rx_index=0;         
        temp = ((temp_data[0]<<8)|temp_data[1]);
        if(temp!=79){ //sometimes i see a 79 in my buffer!
            hc05_flag = 3; //irrelevant flag with this question
            nm=0; //irrelevant flag with this question              
        }
    }
```

it works fine for one time. but after, i see `temp_data[1]` in `temp_data[0]`. it shift 8 bits and i see a big `temp` value (63744 etc.) . where is the problem?

Comment: What is the declaration of `temp_data[]` array?

Comment: You probably have a buffer overrun somewhere.

Comment: Transmitting multi-byte values is generally not something that can be expected to work until you devise and implement an explicit method of synchronization.

Comment: i understand, but how can i transmit 16 bit value in one byte

Comment: You cannot transmit 16 bit in 8 bit. How do you split your 16 bit integer into 2 `temp_bytes` for sending?

Comment: Chris Stratton probably did not mean to put all 16 bit into a single byte but the point is to introduce a mechanism to detect start of such a multi byte transmission.

Comment: Which values do you send?

Comment: my sensor send me two bytes. i store them as `temp_byte1` and `temp_byte2`. i send these values.

Comment: if you want to respond to a comment, please add "@<name>". This generates a notification for the addressed user.

Comment: Again: Which values do you send? How do you split your 16 bit value into 2 8 bit values? If we don't know how you split, how should we tell if you combine correctly? Also without knowing what you send (byte values) we cannot tell if the result is correct.

Comment: top 2 lines on post is how i split 16 bit data into 2 8 bit values while transmitting. i send `0` as byte0 and a value between `50-60` as byte1 generally

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are transmitting integer data via UART, In `HAL_UART_Transmit` you are just passing address of buffer, inside it will be transmitted byte by byte so total 20 bytes will be transmitted.

```
uint16_t txBuffer[10] = {0xFF11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t *) &txBuffer,sizeof(txBuffer), 500);
```

**At Receiver - blocking**

```
uint16_t rxBuffer[10];
void USART6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart6,&rxBuffer,20,500); 
}
```

**At Receiver - Non-blocking**

```
uint16_t rxBuffer[10];
void USART6_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart6,&rxBuffer,20); 
}
```

**NOTE:** In non blocking mode please ensure that reception is over before proceed ahead to use received data because `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` just trigger the interrupt and the copy operation shall be carried out in ISR routine. You can also implement received_done flag to ensure the reception is over.